# Error app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForStagingDebug

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when trying to run my Android project.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForStagingDebug'.
> com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable
```

No idea what this means, and why I'm getting this. Even a Google Search and SO search didn't help. Please help.

Comment: show us your build.gradle and proguard rules

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

My libraries were on an older version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0'
```

After I updated them to the latest version, the problem did not appear again.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'
```

EDIT:

The problem (I found out later) was that my google play services libraries were at different versions.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0'
```

I was getting the error due to this mismatch.